# Django runserver hangs at "System check identified no issues (0 silenced)."

Tags: django, ubuntu

On one Ubuntu box, the project runs just fine with `python manage.py runserver`. When trying to replicate it on another Ubuntu box, after installation, it hangs at `System check identified no issues (0 silenced).` with no further output.

Comment: which Django version?

Answer (score 47):

Just came across the same issue - in my case it happened because the database server was down

EDIT: Django version 1.9

Comment: Thanks, in my case it didn't had access to remote DB. The error message came after several minutes!

Answer (score 21):

when django can't connect to your **database** django run **hangs** at

`System check identified no issues (0 silenced).`
totally issue related **database config**:

1. check database **service** is up
2. check database **Host name** and **Port**
3. check database **UserName** and **Password**
4. check database **User** permission in DB side.

Answer (score 14):

I my case I was attempting to connect to a remote database that wasn't responding to connection requests.

Try `python manage.py dbshell`. This gave me no output. Then I went into amazon web services and relaxed the security settings.

Answer (score 5):

It may be a database connection error.

If you are using AWS for your database, go to the RDS instances tab, click on the security group(s) and edit their inbound/outbound rules to allow connections from the correct host (or from anywhere for a quick fix)

Answer (score 3):

It might worth to read about the [System Check framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/checks/).

```
Serious errors will prevent Django commands (such as runserver) from running at all. Minor problems are reported to the console. If you have inspected the cause of a warning and are happy to ignore it, you can hide specific warnings using the SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS setting in your project settings file.
```

If you don't see any issue being displayed is probably because there were no issues running the system check, if something else is not working the error may not be related, then we need more information.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue and realized it was because i had recently reactivated my VPN so if anyone has a VPN that may be why. Youll need to follow Harry's directions for the fix

Answer (score 1):

Check the DATABASE's host in settings. Make sure it is localhost

Answer (score 0):

There is no `test_` function in my case. Please make sure your file is named `test_~.py` and it must have `def test_~:` inside.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same error because I ran `$ python manage.py runserver` when I was in a Toronto Library.
As soon as I got home, I ran it again, and got no error any more.
I guess that it is because the library firewall blocks port 5432, which  AWS databases run on.

Answer (score 0):

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}
```

if your server gets killed without any error, try this, worked for me
comment above line from settings.py