# Django 2.1.5 on Windows. After runserver: System check identified no issues (0 silenced)

Tags: python, django

This message showed after I executed runserver command:

> System check identified no issues (0 silenced)

I have referenced [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577872/django-runserver-hangs-at-system-check-identified-no-issues-0-silenced), but it didn't work for me(I start my mysql server by the command

> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld"

).

Here is the background information(the "pip list" command):

- (DjangoEnv) D:\pythonproject\DjangoEnv\loginoutonly>pip list
- Package     Version

  ---
- Django      2.1.5
- mysqlclient 1.3.13
- pip         18.1
- PyMySQL     0.9.3
- pytz        2018.9
- setuptools  40.6.3
- wheel       0.32.3

Here is the db information in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'loginoutonly',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'pwd',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306'
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP helped me.
XAMPP says that

> Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!

I change my MySQL port to 3307 using XAMPP [Config] button.
Then, I change my settings.py code to

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'loginoutonly',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3307'
}
```

}

I also need to test the **MySQL WorkBench** connection of this newly connected port "3307".